# How to minimize the remote desktop connection (RDC) window through C#?

Tags: c#, .net, process, rdp, mstsc

The below piece of code makes me to establish a remote desktop connection with the computer machine through mstsc.exe.

```
 string ipAddress = "XXX.XX.XXX.XXX" // IP Address of other machine
 System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = "mstsc.exe";
 proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/v:" + ipAddress ;    
 proc.Start();
```

I want to minimize the RDC window (The mirrow window) once it is launched successfully. Is there any way to do it through C# here ?

This is what I tried, but it makes no difference:

```
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the the `ShowWindow` function from `user32.dll`. Add the following import to your program. You will need a reference to `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
```

What you already have to start RDP will work as you have it, but then you will need to get the new `mstsc` process that is created after the remote desktop opens up. The original process you started exits after `proc.Start()`. Using the code below will get you the first `mstsc` process. NOTE: you should select better than just taking the first if you have more than one RDP window open.

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("mstsc").First();
```

Then call the `ShowWindow` method as shown below with `SW_MINIMIZE = 6`

```
ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, SW_MINIMIZE);
```

The full solution becomes:

```
private const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;
private const int SW_MINIMIZE = 6;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

static void Main(string[] args) {
    string ipAddress = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "mstsc.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/v:" + ipAddress ;    
    proc.Start();

    // NOTE: add some kind of delay to wait for the new process to be created.

    Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("mstsc").First();

    ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, SW_MINIMIZE);
}
```

NOTE: the answer from @Sergio will work, but it will minimize the initial process that is created. If you need to enter credentials, I don't think that is the correct approach.

[Reference for `ShowWindow` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow)

Comment: I tried your solution but it still not minimizes the RDP mirror window.

Comment: @user42067 what do you mean by RDP mirror window? Did you add something to properly delay during the time it takes for the new process to be created?

Comment: The window that launches and let the user see the computer. I mean the window that has three symbols(Network symbol, Lock, pin/unpin) and computer name at the top. I want to minimize that window through C#.

Comment: @user42067 did you wait sufficiently between the end of `proc.Start();` and the next line. See my note about needing to wait for the new process to be created

Comment: @user42067 that certainly works, in my environment, `Thread.Sleep(10000);` is plenty. I did not specify a way to wait in the answer as I do not know enough about your application. Another way would be to monitor the number of `mstsc` processes and wait for a new one to be created. This would be IMO the cleanest solution, but it is up to your implementation

Answer (score -1):

Use windows style, this works.

```
    string ipAddress = "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx"; // IP Address of other machine
    ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("mstsc.exe");
    p.UseShellExecute = true;
    p.Arguments = "/v:" + ipAddress;
    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
    Process.Start(p);
```

Comment: The process starts minimized and then works and responds to what you asked for , if you do NOT have the saved credentials, you open a window where you are asked to enter them, and in this case you are right @ivcubr. Anyway, I just don't understand why you give a negative score to someone who tried to help you.

Comment: Sorry for the negative vote, Please edit your answer so that I can vote it as positive. Your answer was of no use to me though. But thanks for the help.